# Troubles with Paypal Adaptive Payments API

Tags: paypal, coldfusion, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm having trouble with the Chained Payments API, still in development.

Speaking for the sandbox: I've read that, for some reason, the `PayKey` (the unique identifier Paypal creates for the transaction), is not passed back to the transaction. And certainly, in my testing, I get most the data back (like the buyer's email address, name, address information) but I do not get the paykey back.

This field is not just blank, it's not present at all. I'm doing the most basic loop over the `form` scope and writing the results to a file (obviously I won't be doing something this rudimentary in production, this was just to understand what data I was getting).

So I thought I'd pass my own unique identifier, store that in the database, and then pass that through the custom variable. This, (the `custom` field) oddly, comes back blank every time.

Finally I thought I'd just pass it as part of the url of the `IpnNotificationUrl` like `receipt.cfm?myKey=SOMEVERYRANDOMLYGENERATEDKEYHERE` but when I pass `IpnNotificationUrl`, the specified url is not pinged, whether or not I have a separate `IPN Notification URL` setup in my sandbox account. The URL specified in the account is properly pinged each time.

Both files are identical except that they write to differently named text files. I'm not getting an error off either file.

```
<cfoutput><cfsavecontent variable="buildfile">--- Break ---
    <cfloop list="#structkeylist(form)#" index="i">
    #i#: #form[i]#
    </cfloop>
</cfsavecontent></cfoutput>

<cffile file="#expandpath(".")#\dump_new.txt" action="write" output="#buildfile#" />
```

I need to be able to create a key and pass through Paypal or Paypal needs to pass back.

For what it's worth, this is my invocation from Paypal's SDK on GitHub

```
    <cfinvoke component="svc.adaptivepayments" method="payRequest" returnvariable="response">
        <cfinvokeargument name="returnURL" value="#request.serverURL#/success.cfm">
        <cfinvokeargument name="cancelURL" value="#request.serverURL#/cancel.cfm">
        <cfinvokeargument name="ipnNotificationUrl" value="http://myurl/taction/pp_rect2.cfm">
        <cfinvokeargument name="senderEmail" value="">
        <cfinvokeargument name="custom" value="test data">
        <cfinvokeargument name="receiverAmount" value="#ArrayToList(pp_amounts)#">
        <cfinvokeargument name="receiverEmail" value="#ArrayToList(pp_emails)#">
        <cfinvokeargument name="receiverPrimary" value="true,false,false,false,false,false">
        <cfinvokeargument name="feesPayer" value="PRIMARYRECEIVER">
        <cfinvokeargument name="receiverPaymentType" value="DIGITALGOODS,DIGITALGOODS,DIGITALGOODS,DIGITALGOODS,DIGITALGOODS,DIGITALGOODS">
        <cfinvokeargument name="actionType" value="PAY">
        <cfinvokeargument name="currencyCode" value="USD">
    </cfinvoke>
```

Edit: For clarification, Paykey comes back from this service, it's how I generate the link to send the user to paypal. Paykey simply doesn't get passed to my IPN, though other transaction data does. I removed certain information. And I've double checked, none of this information is the paykey or is available at time of paykey creation (so there's no unique identifier on both ends)

--- Break ---

```
    payer_email: redacted

    charset: windows-1252

    item_name: 

    payment_gross: 10.00

    payer_id: A62WKW8N3YDYU

    transaction_subject: 

    item_number: 

    payment_status: Completed

    payment_fee: 0.55

    notify_version: 3.8

    verify_sign: A.CSYz4u5IILQm5wM0J0JbJiIcEuAHODNEgw.2k7ZMYT31eXFO6G0R1o

    mc_currency: USD

    quantity: 0

    residence_country: US

    tax: 0.00

    first_name: John

    receiver_email: redacted

    last_name: Blow

    mc_fee: 0.55

    ipn_track_id: dd4151b653ead

    payer_status: verified

    custom: 

    fieldnames: payer_email,charset,item_name,payment_gross,payer_id,transaction_subject,
    item_number,payment_status,payment_fee,notify_version,verify_sign,
    mc_currency,quantity,residence_country,tax,first_name,receiver_email,
    last_name,mc_fee,ipn_track_id,payer_status,custom,mc_gross,test_ipn,
    business,txn_id,receiver_id,txn_type,payment_type,payment_date,protection_eligibility

    mc_gross: 10.00

    test_ipn: 1

    business: redacted

    txn_id: 71N09598H1922352W

    receiver_id: VBETUFDEQL5BC

    txn_type: web_accept

    payment_type: instant

    payment_date: 12:53:10 Nov 04, 2014 PST

    protection_eligibility: Ineligible
```

Comment: I've never experienced a blank PayKey coming back.  You need the PayKey to redirect to PayPal, so if it was blank it simply wouldn't work at all.  Can you provide the raw API request and response for your Pay call?

Comment: I realize how that seemed confusing, I appended my post this comment: For clarification, Paykey comes back from this service, it's how I generate the link to send the user to paypal. Paykey simply doesn't get passed to my IPN, though other transaction data does.

Comment: I just ran a test Pay request on my server with IPN included, and I'm getting the PayKey back just fine in the IPN details.  You can see a sample of the [app specific IPN here](http://sandbox.angelleye.com/paypal/ipn/admin/raw-log-detail.php?id=6806), which includes the PayKey as expected.  Can you provide the RAW dump of the IPN data you're getting?

Comment: @AndrewAngell I just edited my post with a complete dump, my only edits were to omit specific information and to format the fieldnames item that cold fusion generates with any type of form submission so that it wasn't six miles wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting lost in the fact that Adaptive Payments transactions actually have separate IPN's for the app and for the receiver.  In cases where you're acting as both, you would get 2 separate IPN's.

What you've included here is the receiver/transaction specific IPN.  That would not include a PayKey, but instead, a transaction ID, like you're getting.  You'll notice there is no PayKey parameter at all (as opposed to it being included, but blank, like you originally stated.)

If you want to process app specific data, including the PayKey, you'll need do that from within the app specific IPN, which is what I linked you to for my sample.  You'll notice the parameters it includes are much different than what you're getting here.

In my sample, I was indeed both the app owner and the receiver of the transaction, so I got 2 IPN's at the same time, but of course my IPN script is configured to handle them accordingly.

So again, I had an [app specific IPN](http://sandbox.angelleye.com/paypal/ipn/admin/raw-log-detail.php?id=6806), which includes app specific data including the PayKey.  Then I also got a [separate transaction specific IPN](http://sandbox.angelleye.com/paypal/ipn/admin/raw-log-detail.php?id=6807), which includes data like you're showing here, but does not include a PayKey.

You need to make sure you're handling both correctly.  The IPNNotificationURL parameter in your Pay request would trigger the app specific IPN, where-as the IPN config in the receiver account would trigger the transaction specific IPN.

I see that you are including a value for IPNNotificationURL in your request, but the data you're getting is not that.  You need to check your web server logs because it seems like that one must be failing for some reason, but then the other is hitting and succeeding.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Before your mention above, I hadn't seen a mention of app-specific IPN. It does seem odd that one is working and the other is not (as you said). Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I did resolve my problem, thanks for the advice, but also wanted to say that as I research other paypal related things, I find your name in a lot of spots, like looking for information on GetVerifiedStatus, I found <A href="https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/master/samples/GetVerifiedStatus.php">your php api sample invocation</a>. A tremendous thanks.

Comment: Ha, yeah, I'm kind of a PayPal geek.  That class library is very useful, and I just pushed an update today that is pretty important, so make sure you've got the latest version.